# Fresh Visual Studio Code installation pulls out errors

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just started a fresh **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)** and I get this right from the start:

[image]

Why am I getting these errors and warnings and what do they mean?

Answer (score 0):

Simply enough, the problem turned out to be a left-out comma at my ***last vscode Workspace setting***.

[image]

This is what this means. I think they could have put it in a more specific manner, but hey, all good now.